# tripadvisor scrape restaurant URL and e-mail

Tags: python, web-scraping

Trying to enhance my python skills by making a tripadvisor scraper. 
Currently, the scraper can scrape restaurants in a city and save the name and tripadvisor URL in an excel file. However, I am looking for an advice to also save restaurant e-mail and direct URL.

Can anybody provide any input for this?
Cheers

```html
import requests

from tkinter import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b
from bs4 import Comment as com
from openpyxl import Workbook
# city_name = 'London_England'
# geo_code = '186338'


def o_and_t():
 global nameFile, geo_code, city_name
 nameFile = e_1.get() + '.xlsx'
 geo_code = e_2.get()
 city_name = e_3.get()
 root.destroy()
 return None

def gui():
 global root,e_1,e_2,e_3
 root = Tk()
 root.geometry('500x230')
 root.configure(bg = 'black')
 root.title('Enter Details')
 #
 l_0 = Label(root,text = '\t\tTripAdvisorScraper\n \t\t ~by a1b2t',font = ("Helevetica",14),bg = 'black',fg = 'white')
 l_0.place(x = 0 ,y = 0 )
 #
 l_1 = Label(root,text = 'Please Enter the FileName : ',font = ("Helevetica",11),bg = 'black',fg = 'white')
 l_1.place(x = 0 , y = 60)
 #
 l_2 = Label(root,text = 'Please enter the code from the url : ',font = ("Helevetica",11),bg = 'black',fg = 'white')
 l_2.place(x = 0 , y = 90)
 #
 l_3 = Label(root,text = 'Please enter the city and country as in url :',font = ("Helevetica",12),bg = 'black',fg = 'white')
 l_3.place(x = 0,y = 120)
 #
 e_1 = Entry(root)
 e_1.place(x = 320 ,y = 60)
 #
 e_2 = Entry(root)
 e_2.place(x = 320 ,y = 90)
 #
 e_3 = Entry(root)
 e_3.place(x = 320 ,y = 120)
 #
 b_1 = Button(root,text = 'START',command = o_and_t)
 b_1.place(x = 220 ,y = 170)
 root.mainloop()
 return None


gui()

print('\n\n\tStarting Scraper\t\n\n')



main_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurants-g{}-{}.html'.format(geo_code, city_name)

'https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/RestaurantSearch?Action=PAGE&geo=186338&ajax=1&itags=10591&sortOrder=relevance&o=a150&availSearchEnabled=false'
'https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/RestaurantSearch?Action=PAGE&geo=186338&ajax=1&itags=10591&sortOrder=relevance&o=a60&availSearchEnabled=false'
'https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/RestaurantSearch?Action=PAGE&geo=186338&ajax=1&itags=10591&sortOrder=relevance&o=a30&availSearchEnabled=false'

req_1 = requests.get(main_url)
soup = b(req_1.content, 'html.parser')
total_pages = int(soup.find_all('a', class_="pageNum taLnk")[-1]['data-page-number']) + 1
print(total_pages)
RESULTS = []

for page_no in range(0, total_pages*30 , 30):
 page_no
 url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/RestaurantSearch?Action=PAGE&geo={}&ajax=1&itags=10591&sortOrder=relevance&o=a{}&availSearchEnabled=false'.format(geo_code, page_no)
 req_2 = requests.get(url)
 soup_2 = b(req_2.content, 'html.parser')
 temp = soup_2.find_all('a', class_="property_title")
 for t in temp:
  r_name = t.text.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '') 

  r_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com' + t['href']
  print(str([r_name, r_url]).encode()) 
  RESULTS.append([r_name, r_url])


if len(RESULTS) !=0:  
 wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
 ws = wb.create_sheet()
 for steps_0 in RESULTS:
  ws.append(steps_0)
 wb.save(nameFile)
print(len(RESULTS))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just scrape each URL you are grabbing and look for element class="detail_section info"